# How to print stack trace from Java Mac Os X Application Bundle

Tags: java, macos, stack-trace

I have a processing based Java application that runs fine in Eclipse but the Application bundle that I build crashes on launch. I want to print a stack trace so I can figure out what is causing the problem. I think this should be pretty straight forward but I can't find an example of this anywhere (maybe my terminology is incorrect?)

OS X 10.6.7
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07-334-10M3326)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02-334, mixed mode)

Comment: Have you tried viewing the logs files? You can do this by using the Application "console" located in /Applications/Utilities. Normally, the jvm should log unexpected crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the system log? Launch the Console app and see if the stack trace is printing there.